# How to pass images on QGraphicsView to QTableView programmatically using QPushButton

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5, qtableview, qgraphicsview

I have been researching for a while how to store images loaded on a `QGraphicsView` into rows of a `QTableView` using a `QPushButton` in a programmatic way but the information I found so far are not that many.

I have 1 `QGraphicsView`, a `QPushButton` (Send button) and a `QTableView` and a `QLineEdit`. When I upload images using the load button I show them both on the `QGraphicsView` and on the `QLineEidt` (I show the path of the image), if I click the Send button, the text of the `QLineEdit` should be added in the first row of the `QTableView` (which is happening) and the image should be stored inside the `QTableView`.

However, the image on the `QGraphicsView` is not being stored to the `QTableView` and nothing is being passed.

**Currently this is what happens:**

[image: wrong]

**The expected behavior would be:**

[image: expected]

I created an `ItemDelegate` class that takes care of the resizing of the image on the `QGraphicsView` to be stored inside the `QTableView` 
That part is shown below:

This is the **mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "imagedelegate.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void addData();
    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;

private slots:
    void on_sendBtn_clicked();
    void on_loadBtn_clicked();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
    QGraphicsScene *leftScene;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and here is the **mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "imagedelegate.h"
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QBuffer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    leftScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(leftScene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
    model = new QStandardItemModel();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::addData()
{
    // Path on the first column
    QStandardItem *pathAItem = new QStandardItem(ui->lineEdit->text());

    // Image on the second column - not working yet
    //QStandardItem *image1 = new QStandardItem(/*ui->graphicsView->*/);

    QPixmap image1;
    QByteArray img1Array;
    QBuffer buffer1(&img1Array);
    buffer1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    image1.save(&buffer1, "PNG");

    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    row << pathAItem;
    model->setColumnCount(1);
    model->appendRow(row);
}

void MainWindow::on_sendBtn_clicked()
{
    addData();
}



void MainWindow::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QString colName = index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal).toString();
    if(colName == "image1")
    {
        QPixmap iconPix;
        if(!iconPix.loadFromData(index.model()->data(index).toByteArray())) {
        }
        iconPix = iconPix.scaledToHeight(32);
        painter->drawPixmap(option.rect.x(),option.rect.y(),iconPix);
    } else {
//        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

The entire code will compile if you copy and paste so that you can see the issue I have.

Please shed light on this matter.

Comment: I wonder if, instead of writing a custom delegate, you might get the behavior you want simply by calling `setIcon(QIcon(myLoadedPixmap))` on your `QStandardItem` object?  Either way can be made to work, but the `setIcon()` approach is a lot easier.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner and thanks for taking the time to read the question. How can I modify the code I wrote with your suggestion?

Comment: Get rid of the `ImageDelegate` class, but use the iconPixmap code you wrote (`iconPixmap->loadFromData()`, etc) to set up a `QPixmap` object that contains your image, and then call `pathAItem->setIcon(iconPixmap);`

Comment: Ok I edited the question cutting down to the minimum. Going without `Delegate` is a good idea. The program still does not compile though. I am setting the image inside the `void MainWindow::paint()` function but nothing happens.

Comment: You don't need any `paint()` method AFAIK.  Put your code inside `addData()` instead.

Comment: Ok small progress see [here](https://i.imgur.com/smtJ4md.png). I am understanding the process but I am still not catching how to get rid of the two remaining errors.

Comment: Dunno about the first error, but for the second error you can just delete the call to `drawPixmap()`, since you don't need it, you already have the `QPixmap` object you need.

Comment: Ok thanks that worked!! If you can post the edited code I can mark your answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to answer to this question hoping that could also be useful to others. As suggested by Jeremy Friesner, the best (and fast in comparison to a `QItemDelegate`) way to send images into a `QTableView` using a `QPushButton` is to modify the `void MainWindow::addData()` function by using a `QImage` and pass it to a `setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage), Qt::DecorationRole)` so that the entire function can be written as follows:

**FIRST OPTION**:

```
void MainWindow::on_sendBtn_clicked()
{
    addData();
}

void MainWindow::addData()
{
    QStandardItem *pathAItem = new QStandardItem(ui->pathLineEdit_A->text());
    QStandardItem *pathBItem = new QStandardItem(ui->pathLineEdit_B->text());

    QImage image1(ui->graphicsViewLeft->grab().toImage());
    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem();
    item1->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(image1.scaled(42,42, Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation))), Qt::DecorationRole);
    ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(model);

    QImage image2(ui->graphicsViewRight->grab().toImage());
    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem();
    item2->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(image2.scaled(42,42, Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation))), Qt::DecorationRole);
    ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(model);

    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    row << pathAItem << pathBItem << item1 << item2;
    model->appendRow(row);
}
```

**SECOND OPTION**

If it is necessary to use a `QItemDelgate` I am posting that part of the code too (it is working as I already tried it):

In the **imagedelegate.h** is necessary to provide a `QSize` as follows:

```
class ImageDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    ImageDelegate(QObject * parent = nullptr);
    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;
```

After that on your **imagedelegate.cpp** the implementation is:

```
#include "imagedelegate.h"
ImageDelegate::ImageDelegate(QObject * parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{}

QSize ImageDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    return QSize(32,32);
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(index);
}

void ImageDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    qDebug() << (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal).toString());
    QString colName = index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal).toString();

    if(colName == "image1" || colName == "image2")
    {
        QPixmap iconPix;
        if(!iconPix.loadFromData(index.model()->data(index).toByteArray())) {
        }
        iconPix = iconPix.scaledToHeight(32);
        painter->drawPixmap(option.rect.x(),option.rect.y(),iconPix);
    } else {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

In my case I had two columns in which I needed to save the images, so you can expand it for how many columns as you like and I also set a `QSize` of `(32,32)` but this is up to the developer.

I hope this will save your programming time and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEWPj.png) is the final result! :)